# How to create condition "If cell is blank and other cells in same row are not blank"?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I need cell A1 to be highlighted if it's blank AND any cell in the same row is NOT blank. Most of the cells in the row will have formulas in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new conditional format, and use this formula:

`=AND($A$1="",COUNTA(1:1)>=1)`

and then "Format" -> "Fill" and choose your color.

When `A1` is NOT blank, there's no fill in.

When `A1` is blank, AND there's a value in the same row somewhere, there will be fill in.

When `A1` is blank, and the rest of the row is blank too, no fill.

Comment: This isn't working for me. It's highlighting the cell even when the entire row is blank. If it matters, the cell is actually A78, so I changed this formula to this:  `=AND($A$78="",COUNTA(1:1)>=1)`

Comment: Ah - change the `Counta()` rows to 78 as well.  `=AND($A$78="",COUNTA(78:78)>=1`.  What it does is check that both A78 *is* blank, and if row 78 has at least one cell with data in it. `Counta()` checks a range for non-blank cells.

Answer (score 3):

Enter this formula in Conditional Formatting:

```
=(A1="")*COUNTA(1:1)
```

The above will count blanks from a formula as not being truly blank. If you wish for the Conditional Formatting to ignore these types of blanks then you can use this formula instead:

```
=(A1="")*SUMPRODUCT((1:1<>"")+0)
```

Comment: That's pretty clever, nice use of the TRUE/FALSE being `1` or `0`.

Comment: Could I ask you to please refrain from using comments to ask people to look at your answer? Askers are notified about every answer that is left to their questions, and comments like this are generally frowned upon here. They are under no obligation to accept any answer.

Comment: This isn't working for me. It's highlighting the cell even when the entire row is blank. If it matters, the cell is actually A78, so I changed this formula to this:  
`=(A78="")*COUNTA(1:1)`

Comment: @Robby It matters! Here is what to do... Delete the conditional format you just made. Now... select all of column A by clicking the 'A' header on the sheet. Then go into Conditional Formatting. Select New Rule and then Use a formula. Now enter the formula EXACTLY like in my answer... just copy and paste it without changing any characters. Then select your formatting and save it. That will do it.

Comment: That's not working quite right either. To be clear, if A78 is blank, but there are any actual values (not a formula) in any cells in that row, A78 should be highlighted.  After doing what you just told me, it's seemingly highlighting random cells in the A column. For example, A83 is highlighted, but I have triple checked that nothing are in any of those cells in that row.

Comment: @robby. Yep. The formula will count blanks produced by formulas. If you wish to exclude those blanks as well, then you can use this version of the formula:   `=(A1="")*SUMPRODUCT((1:1<>"")+0)`

Comment: @Robby Did the SUMPRODUCT() version of the formula meet your needs?

Comment: Well, it didn't seem to work. But I did get the suggestion below to work. Thanks.

Comment: @Robby It works. You must have a cell that is not truly blank. But I'm glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
=(G1="")*SUMPRODUCT((1:1<>"")+0)
```

Works, for column G being blank when row has another cell populated.